# php - mysql storing old data

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm with a quite annoying situation.

One application's user is having problem getting updated data from my database. Here as follow:

1. The user generate an insert statement into my database.
2. When the user list these inserts, he only got the data that was previous there when he login into my application, only after some minutes he can see the data that he sends a while back ago.

I'm executing simple and plain statements of insert and select, and only this user is getting this problem, the rest of my users are fine.

Is it possible that somewhat the value that I retrieve from the data base is being cached?

Comment: this can certainly be the case with browsers and plopping a different url with a junk huge random number at end of url can solve that scenario

Comment: ie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540898/php-mysql-storing-old-data?my_junk=93883766d6837fb9887

Comment: I remember doing this on javascript, but I never, NEVER, realize that this can happen to php and mysql.

Comment: it would be unrelated entirely with mysql. the browser caches the php url, pulls the junk from cache thinking all is well

Comment: thanks guys. I'm gonna try this with my client and see what happens. Is something so simple that I could never guess. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in flash i would have a 'long' magicnumber that would increment perpetually. then subsequent calls to the url would increment the magicnumber and add it to the url.

such as

url="http://example.com?property=948&angle=street-corner&magicnumber=837493"